# Did Euler know (unconsciously) to integrate by differentiating?

Tags: real-analysis, ho.history-overview

Considering a method to find the anti-derivative of an (sufficiently smooth) real function by differentiating published some years ago (equation (48) in [Kempf et al., New Dirac Delta function based methods with
applications to perturbative expansions in quantum
field theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.0747.pdf)):
\begin{equation}
\int^x f(x')\,dx' = \lim_{y \to 0} f\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right) \frac{\mathrm{e}^{xy}-1}{y} +C, 
\end{equation}
I'm wondering whether Euler in his very imaginative calculations (to say the least) did use some techniques (in special cases) that amount to this formula.

Any hints are welcome.

Comment: The formula just seems to be a funny way of saying that one can integrate a power series term by term.

Comment: In principle yes. But nevertheless it can help in performing integrals. At least it has been implemented in Maple from version 2019 onwards, according to https://uwaterloo.ca/physics-of-information-lab/).

Comment: Since this is a question about what Euler knew, rather than about mathematics *per se*, it seems like a better fit for [HSMSE](http://hsm.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Could you give an example of a specific integral which is evaluated by this formula?

Comment: One of the simplest examples is $f(x) = \exp(x)$, so $f(\partial_y)g(y)=g(y+1)$ and you get by the formula above the anti–derivative $\exp(x)–1+C$.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't know about that particular integral, but Euler certainly knew about integrating by differentiating. He wrote about it in his *Exposition de quelques paradoxes dans le calcul integral* (1758). A recent summary of that work can be found in

A. Fabian and H.D. Nguyen,
Paradoxical Euler: integrating by differentiating,
*The Mathematical Gazette* **97** (2013), no. 538, 61-74.

Comment: (this is certainly far off-topic and I will delete it shortly, but I would like to say I am a big fan of your twitter account!)